# How can I truncate the selected text in a delphi combobox?

Tags: delphi, combobox

I have a combobox with its style set to csDropDown. I am trying to do this in the OnSelect event handler;

```
if cboEndTime.ItemIndex > -1 then
  cboEndTime.Text := AnsiLeftStr(cboEndTime.Text, 5);
```

but it has no effect.

The combo items look like this;

09:00 (0 minutes)
09:30 (30 minutes)
10:00 (1 hour)
10:30 (1.5 hours)
...

If i select the second item for example, I want the text of the combobox to show 09:30, ie truncated. Which would set ItemIndex to -1.

How can I achive this?

Comment: Yes, it is csDropDown. Why is this not possible? I can set text from other code and type whatever I like. I could understand if it was csDropDownList, but it's not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would appear that changes that you make to `Text` during the `OnSelect` event are subsequently overwritten by the framework. Either the Windows API, or the VCL, I have not investigated which.

One solution is to postpone the actual change until processing of the original input event has completed. Like this:

```
const
  WM_COMBOSELECTIONCHANGED = WM_USER;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ComboBox1: TComboBox;
    procedure ComboBox1Select(Sender: TObject);
  protected
    procedure WMComboSelectionChanged(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_COMBOSELECTIONCHANGED;
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.ComboBox1Select(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PostMessage(Handle, WM_COMBOSELECTIONCHANGED, 0, 0);
end;

procedure TForm1.WMComboSelectionChanged(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
  if ComboBox1.ItemIndex<>-1 then
  begin
    ComboBox1.Text := Copy(ComboBox1.Text, 1, 1);
    ComboBox1.SelectAll;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set the Style to OwnerDrawFixed and Paint the wished Text using OnDrawItem on your own.
The lookup in this example would show all, the selection only the trimmed string.

```
procedure TForm3.ComboBox1DrawItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer;
  Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);

  var
   C:TComboBox;

  Function Strip(const s:String):String;
    begin
       if C.DroppedDown then result := s
       else Result := Copy(s,1,pos('(',s)-1);
    end;
begin
     C := TComboBox(Control);
     C.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
     C.Canvas.TextOut(Rect.left + 1,Rect.Top + 1, Strip(C.Items[Index] ));
end;
```

Comment: If I owner draw the control won't the underlying value still be incorrect? Worse inconsistant with that displayed visually. Wouldn't this make editing the text really difficult?

Comment: That's correct, I interpreted `to show 09:30` as just showing the value changed, not changing it. Instead of accessing the Text direct if you want to uses `9:30` only you could access the value via Stripped(Combobox.Items[Combobox.ItemIndex]) where Stripped would be used in the `Result :=` part of above `Function Strip` and for accessing the Items. But have a look @DavidHeffernan 's solution, it will fit better for you.